# Text and Input are not on the same line

Tags: javascript, checkbox, createelement

I am trying to create an "on an off switch" for a project where I can get a questionnaire group of elements. When you run the following code, you will see a div appear on the screen in a group of elements. The text is above the checkbox, I need them to be side by side. Any ideas?

```js
var bigDiv = document.createElement("div")
var fem = document.createElement("P");
var t = document.createTextNode("FooText");
var femI = document.createElement("INPUT");
bigDiv.style.display = 'block';
fem.appendChild(t);
bigDiv.appendChild(fem);
femI.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
bigDiv.appendChild(femI);
bigDiv.setAttribute("id", "demChoosing")
document.body.appendChild(bigDiv);
```

P.S - the key words 'fem' and 'demChoosing' don't mean anything

Comment: Hey Darrow. I've made a decently drastic edit to your question's code, not only to remove unrelated code, but also to forego the need to supply users with "instructions" to replicate the issue.  If you disagree with my edit, you can roll it back, or let me know and I gladly will!

Comment: ^ That all aside, it seems like your question doesn't actually relate to javascript at all, but rather just basic styling principles. `<p>` elements are block-level. This means that by default, they have `display: block;` applied. The behavior of `display: block;`, barring specific cases (`float`, `flex`, etc) is to be on their *own line* (by occupying the entirety of the bounding area's width). You could override this by setting the `p` to `display: inline` using CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is simple: `p` elements are rendered as block-elements. So they use the whole available width. You can try to set the display type to "inline" or "inline-block" to put the `p` tag and the `input` tag in the same line.

```js
var bigDiv = document.createElement("div")
var fem = document.createElement("P");
var t = document.createTextNode("FooText");
var femI = document.createElement("INPUT");
bigDiv.style.display = 'block';
fem.appendChild(t);
bigDiv.appendChild(fem);
femI.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
fem.setAttribute('style', 'display: inline-block;')
bigDiv.appendChild(femI);
bigDiv.setAttribute("id", "demChoosing")
document.body.appendChild(bigDiv);
```